# Filtering mongodb geospatial return data?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a geospatial collection that's working well -- given a simple query and data return like this:

```
    > distance = db.runCommand({ geoNear : "geodata_geo", near : [-121.8993988, 36.9771729], spherical : true, maxDistance : range / earthRadius, num : 3 }).results;
[
    {
        "dis" : 0,
        "obj" : {
            "CountryID" : 231,
            "_id" : ObjectId("4ecea8348044dc9bdd21eda3"),
            "cityCode" : "3183347",
            "cityID" : 952717,
            "cityName" : "Aptos",
            "countryCode" : "US",
            "countryName" : "United States",
            "countyCode" : "US005044",
            "countyID" : 5932,
            "countyName" : "Santa Cruz",
            "**id_geo**" : 952717,
            "lat" : 36.9771728515625,
            "loc" : {
                "lon" : -121.8993988,
                "lat" : 36.9771729
            },
            "lon" : -121.89939880371094,
            "regionCode" : "NAm",
            "regionID" : 1078,
            "regionName" : "North America",
            "stateCode" : "US005",
            "stateID" : 3725,
            "stateName" : "California"
        }
    },
```

Is there a way to form this query so that I  only return the (list of) id_geo values from within the collection?  I've tried several variations but none seem to give me what I need...I know I can handle this programmatically, but was wondering if this was mongopossible...

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need `geoNear`? The [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-geoNearCommand) indicate that "the find() syntax above is typically preferred".

If you're OK with find(), then it's easy. Returning all fields:

```
db.customers.find({ "addresses.billing_address.location" : 
  { $within : { $center : [[-117.15,32.72],0.15] } } }
)
```

Returning the same documents but only the account_type field:

```
db.customers.find({ "addresses.billing_address.location" : 
  { $within : { $center : [[-117.15,32.72],0.15] } } }, {"account_type" : 1} 
)
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  I needed the geoNear to get the distanceFrom returned in the query as that has to be returned back to the front end.  I'll just handle it programmatically within a different flow for when I need that data.  

Two birds, two stones....

Thanks again!

Comment: In that case you really do need geoNear. I guess the only thing you can do is handle it as you suggest. Well... that and log it as an enhancement request.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the `fields` parameter:

```
db.runCommand({ geoNear : "geodata_geo", 
                near : [-121.8993988, 36.9771729], 
                spherical : true, 
                maxDistance : 45, 
                num : 3 }, 
              {fields : { "obj.id_geo" : 1 } }).results;
```

This is documented for the [`findAndModify` command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command).

Comment: Sorry, I answered this on a hunch. I tried a few different approaches now, and I couldn't bend the `geoNear` results to my will at all :( I won't delete the answer so people can see it does not work this way.